# Scripts and Stylesheets wont accept script?

Tags: magento2, javascript, script

**Magento 2.3.3**

I am inserting a script into the scripts and stylesheet section of my shop. As soon as there is a `<script>...</script>`, it wont add it. If I add the script without the surrounding `<script></script>` tags, it works. Inserting a style `<style>...</style>` works without any problems.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to add script using the XML file.

Comment: Its a Matomo script and I need different ones for each store...

Comment: ok so could you try like this?
https://tinyurl.com/yy5spg6d

Comment: I tried, it just cuts it out, I only get the 2 comments, the rest disappears! If I put space in the script tags like < script >, it does not cut it out, but then the code is invalid.

Comment: I am trying with various Magento versions, it is working as expected at my end.

Comment: magento customise script type for use of "text/x-magento-init" json. So you could not use it with <script type="text/javascript">

Answer (score 0):

Go to `app/design/frontend/Project/default/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml`

There you can define your custom js and css

Here is an example with multiples data

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <meta name="robots" content="INDEX,FOLLOW"/>
        <css src="sprites/sprites.css"/>
        <css src="glyphs/style.css"/>

        <css src="slick/slick.css"/>
        <css src="slick/slick-theme.css"/>

        <css src="magnific_popup/magnific-popup.css"/>

        <link src="js/custom.js"/>


    </head>
</page>
```